# Cells is not null but it shows null

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which i took from online and it works. However, there is some issue when i tried to increase the range

This code works

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim strString$, x&
    strString = Range("B1").Value

    With Range("A1")
        .Font.ColorIndex = 1
        For x = 1 To Len(.Text) - Len(strString) Step 1
            If Mid(.Text, x, Len(strString)) = strString Then .Characters(x, Len(strString)).Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

This doesnt

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim strString$, x&
    strString = Range("B1").Value

    **With Range("A1:A2")**
        .Font.ColorIndex = 1
        **For x = 1 To Len(.Text) - Len(strString) Step 1**
            If Mid(.Text, x, Len(strString)) = strString Then .Characters(x, Len(strString)).Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

I am sure that my cell A1 and A2 is not null. However, when i did it ran it in debug mode, it shows that Len(.Text) is null. However, when i tried to do it in this way it works

This works too

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim strString$, x&
    strString = Range("B1").Value

    With Range("A2")
        .Font.ColorIndex = 1
        For x = 1 To Len(.Text) - Len(strString) Step 1
            If Mid(.Text, x, Len(strString)) = strString Then .Characters(x, Len(strString)).Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Based on the debugger the error lies in this code

```
Len(.Text) which is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop for all cells in the range, so the code should look like that:

```
Sub Test1()
Dim rng As Range
Dim strString$, x&
strString = Range("B1").Value
For Each rng In Range("A2:A3")
    rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    For x = 1 To Len(rng.Text) - Len(strString) Step 1
       If Mid(rng.Text, x, Len(strString)) = strString Then rng.Characters(x, Len(strString)).Font.ColorIndex = 5
    Next x
Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you cannot call `.Text` on a range containing multiple cells. You will need to iterate through the range cells first to continune processing them one at a time.